# How to show a mesaage indicating that username is incorrect in spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've created a login page and made the configuration of spring security to authenticate users dynamically from database.
this is my userservice that do the check of authenticated users

```
@Inject
@Named(value = "dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource1;

ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection connection = null;
String name;
String pwd;

final String select_auth = "select username,password from users";

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("in userService...");

     String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();

    try {
        connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select_auth);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
             name=resultSet.getString("username");
             pwd =resultSet.getString("password");
                if(name.equals(username)&& pwd.equals(password)){
                    return auth;
                }

                    return null;
            }



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }

    }
     return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, pwd);
        }

public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

    return true;
}

}
```

And this is my login.jsp page

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form"
        action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='post'>

        <div class="header">
            <h1>S'authentifier</h1>
            <span> ${auth}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <input name="j_username" type="text" class="input username"
                value="Utilisateur" onfocus="this.value=''" /> <input
                name='j_password' type="password" class="input password"
                value="Mot de passe" onfocus="this.value=''" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer"      class="button" />
        </div>


    </form>

</div>

<div class="gradient"></div>

</body>
```

My problem is how to show a message in the login page that tells that the username is incorrect or the password is incorrect ? and where to do the check? can i check it in the userService ?

Comment: You usually *shouldn't* do this, because it allows attackers to guess valid usernames.

Comment: @chrylis is right in that an application should not reveal that it knows (or does not know) a particular username as it assists hackers in collecting usernames registered with an application and launch slow dictionary and brute-force password attacks.  If you still want to go ahead, see [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#localization) from the official documentation.  You can configure your own messages for each   scenario in which authentication could fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and especially  for your advice,  but I want to know how  and where to do the check and to understand the mechanism of returning messages to the jsp file ,eventhough I'm not going to integrate it in my application..

Comment: You don't need to perform any checks.  `UserDetailsService` is just a DAO (see its JavaDocs).  The checks are performed in an implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` which raises appropriate exceptions for user-not-found, bad-password, inactive-user, user-locked-out, etc.  These exceptions then get translated to messages using a `messages.properties` file that comes bundled with the Spring Security JAR.  The localized message for the exception is then directly passed to the login-failure-page.  See the section I linked to for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @manich